# Passing Instance to Shared Method in VB.NET

Tags: ajax, vb.net, methods, shared

I have been thrown in at the deep end with an existing VB.NET project at work.  I have never used VB.NET before so I am struggling a little.  Does anyone know how to solve the following.

I need to pass an instance to client side and then pass it to a shared method in order to access instance methods from when the shared method.

The starting point is a fileupload control within the HTML of my Contacts.aspx file:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="DocUpload1" runat="server" onchange="CallMe();" />
```

The onchange event calls a javascript method, see below, this uses AJAX PageMethods to called a Shared method in my code behind

This is the script code which is in my Contact.aspx file

```
    <script language="javascript">
      function CallMe() {
          // call server side method
          PageMethods.GetContact(0, CallSuccess, CallFailed, null);
      }

      // set the destination textbox value with the ContactName
      function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {
      }

      // alert message on some failure
      function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
          alert(res.get_message());
      }        

</script>
```

This is an example class of the type of thing I want to do, I think I need to use the "instance As Contacts" as an input parameter to the WebMethod function but I don't know how to pass the instance into it:

This is the class within my Contacts.aspx.vb file.

```
Partial Class Contacts

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetContact(ByVal instance As Contacts) As String
        Return instance.GetContactName()  'This is an instance class which I need to call.
    End Function

    'This is my instance class which I want to call from the Shared Class.
    Public Shared Function GetContactName() As String
        Return "Fred Bloggs"
    End Function

End Class
```

If anyone knows the solution please could they update the code as I probably won't be able to understand if you just give a description.  I just hope I am along the right tracks.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're actually doing. What is Contacts for a class(JS or VB.Net), why do you need to pass it to the server and why can't you call GetContactName(if it's a JS-"class")on clientside?
If its a .Net Class you should pass the ContactID(if something like this is available) to the WebMethod and create an instance on serverside.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to access a class (your `instance`) created in the ASP.Net page life-cycle from your `PageMethod` - eg created during initial page load or file upload etc.

This is not directly possible as PageMethods do not go through the full page life-cycle (they are essentially webservices). So you need to pass some sort of identifier to the client that, when passed back to the server in the `PageMethod`, can be used to re-create or retrieve your `instance`.

eg During the initial page load:

```
session("ContactID") = instance
```

Your PageMethod might look something like:

```
Public Shared Function GetContact(ByVal key As String) As String
    Return HttpContext.Current.Session(key).GetContactName()  
End Function
```

where the parameter `key` is the same key you used to store your instance in the session state.

In your javascript:

```
 function CallMe() {
          // call server side method
          PageMethods.GetContact('ContactID', CallSuccess, CallFailed, null);
 }
```

Comment: I was puklled off the project to do some other work but now I am back on it, it was nice to see the answer I have been looking for.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @EnterpriseMonkey - Glad it was helpful. You can vote up and accept the answer to show your appreciation :)